# Getting the value from a specific Gridview Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access the value of a cell in my `GridView`. I want to access the value by the cell's name, rather than by the index. How can I do this?

I do not want to access the cell by its index because there is a chance that it will change positions at any time. I know that `Cells[0]` would give me the value of the first index, but how about if I want to do something like `Cells["NameOfCell"]?`

Note: I cannot use the `GridView` events because all the existing code is doing it in a function called `Bind()` and they have something like this

```
public void Bind()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        //need to access the specific value here by name
        //I know this is wrong but you get the idea
        string test = row.Cells["NameOfCell"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the markup? If you're binding the value to a control within a particular cell, it's easy to retrieve. However, you're just evaluating the value and placing it in a cell, that limits your options considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just 4 fun:

```
private int nameCellIndex = -1;
private const string CellName = "Name";

void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].Text == CellName)
            {
                nameCellIndex = cellIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (nameCellIndex != -1 && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string test = e.Row.Cells[nameCellIndex].Text;
    }
}
```

the same, not using RowDataBound:

```
private int nameCellIndex = -1;
private const string CellName = "Name";

void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
    {
        if (GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[cellIndex].Text == CellName)
        {
            nameCellIndex = cellIndex;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (nameCellIndex != -1)
    {
        foreach (var row in GridView1.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Where(row => row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
        {
            string test = row.Cells[nameCellIndex].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, get the data from your data source - the GridView should be used for displaying data and not retrieving it.  It's bound to your data source, so you should be well-equipped to read from the data source too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from the `GridView Row DataItem`

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx